# Alternate method for renaming files in android using java

Tags: java, android

Is there another way to rename a file without using using **File.renameTo** method? also, I am new to android, so asking this question :  Is there a way to rename a file without making the code to open that file?

I want to just **rename** the file, not open it or copy its contents.

Comment: But to copy the content of a file, I have to open it. I want to **just** rename the file, not open it.

Comment: Is your file in the sdcard ?

Comment: I'm just curious, is there any reason that File.renameTo shouldn't be used? I would want to know if there are any drawbacks to this method, as I am currently using it.

Comment: No this is a file belonging to a system app on a rooted phone. I am unable to copy the file belonging to that system app through the code of **my** system app. It gives permission denied error for EACCES. I have added all required permissions so that is not the problem.

Comment: @Gautham What is your problem with `renameTo` method ?

Comment: reNameto requires that the file has to be **opened** to rename it, I want to know whether I can just rename the file **without** having to open it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Renaming the file by moving it to a new name. (FileUtils is from Apache Commons IO lib)

```
  String newFilePath = oldFile.getAbsolutePath().replace(oldFile.getName(), "") + newName;
  File newFile = new File(newFilePath);

  try {
    FileUtils.moveFile(oldFile, newFile);
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```